# Django models date time field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a model that should only accept dates 15 days from today and store the start and end time and show an error when we enter an end time before the start time.

Comment: So... the start time should be no sooner than today + 15 days?

Comment: Sounds like a form validation task. Do you really want to put it on the model level?

Answer (score 0):

The models clean functions are what you're looking for.

This is an example right from the django documentation to start off:

```
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
        if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
        # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
        if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
            self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

For further details read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects